# Angular change input value, name and label on repeatable element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to change the input name, value and label on a repeatable element.

```
<div class="input" ng-repeat='value in configOption.values track by $index'>
<label>{OptionName}</label>
  <a ng-click="" ng-init="">Change between OPT1 and OPT2</a>
  <input type="text" ng-model="value.opt1" placeholder="OPT1">
</div>
```

The expected result:

When i am clicking the a element to toggle the input and change the Label
From: `<input type="text" ng-model="value.opt1" placeholder="OPT1">`
To `<input type="text" ng-model="value.opt2" placeholder="OPT2">`

Being that the entire div is a repeatable element.

Any idea how can i deal with this ?

Comment: You can do some data binding

Comment: Can you also show what you're expecting the result to be? I don't see a label and in angular you wouldn't really use `name`, you would use `ng-model` and the value is set by the user and stored in the dataset via ng-model. Please flush out your question so people can understand exactly what you're trying to accomplish